# Need to run a script and use nvidia-settings to make CUDA available (from my nvidia GPU). Is there a quicker way?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia-settings

My laptop has two graphics units - Intel HD graphics and a 2015 nvidia GPU. Whenever I want to switch to the GPU, I need to do the following two steps:

**Step 1: Run a script**

```
echo Updating alternatives
sudo update-alternatives --set x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf /usr/lib/nvidia-352-prime/ld.so.conf
sudo update-alternatives --set i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf /usr/lib/nvidia-352-prime/alt_ld.so.conf

echo "Starting nvidia-352"
sudo modprobe nvidia-352
```

**Step 2: Use nvidia-settings**

```
# Open nvidia-settings
# Select Nvidia, enter my password (gsudo) and then quit the window.
```

Is there a way I can incorporate *Step 2* into my script in *Step 1*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening `nvidia-settings` essentially run prime-select. Here is what the CLI equivalent looks like:

```
prime-select nvidia
```

So now my script looks like this:

```
echo Updating alternatives
sudo update-alternatives --set x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf /usr/lib/nvidia-352-prime/ld.so.conf
sudo update-alternatives --set i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf /usr/lib/nvidia-    352-prime/alt_ld.so.conf

echo "Starting nvidia-352"
sudo modprobe nvidia-352

sudo prime-select nvidia
```